# How should I handle a counter where the numbers do not have a pattern?

Tags: macros, counters

I am working on homework and problems are assigned from several sections of a book. For example, I have to solve problems 1, 7, 24 from section 1 and problems 2, 5, 9 from section 2. I do not care about section numbering so my counter would go 1 -> 7 -> 24 -> 2 -> 5 -> 9.

I have been typing all of this up via `\begin{enumerate}` and `\setcounter` which has become quite the hassle. My question is two-fold.

Should I continue using enumerate or should I do something else? (self-numbering, etc.)

Assuming yes to the above, how do I streamline the process of numbering? I tried to write something like `\newcommand{foobar}[2]{\setcounter{#1}{#2}\addtocounter{#1}{-1}\item}`
 but have had no such luck.

Comment: if you are using enumerate you don't need the counter settings just `\item[7]`... `\item[24]` ...

Comment: @Sigur 18 seconds quicker than me, do you want to make that an answer:-)

Comment: That was exactly what I was looking for. Thank you both. Either one of you can feel free to turn that into an answer.

Comment: @Sigur seems a reasonable question with a reasonable answer. I've posted shorted ones:-)

Comment: @DavidCarlisle, OK. I tried to make it longer and more exemplified.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Every time you use a list with items you can replace the default item label using, for example,

```
\item[7]  Item contents here.
\item[24] Item contents here.
```

Or if you want an empty item just use `\item[]`.

Those commands will not affect the list margins/alignments.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle But where's the proof now?!

Comment: @cfr, ow, so sorry. I deleted! But after some time both comments would be the same time ago.

Comment: @cfr you don't need proof, just faith in the accuracy of my comments!

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Philosophers against irrationality!

Comment: When you mouse over it it shows the exact time.